# How to define access keys for an Explorer context menu item?

Tags: windows-7, context-menu, shell-extensions

*Suppose* i want to create a menu item for folders which opens the command line in that folder, to that end i can add some keys in the registry, namely

```
HKLM > Software > Classes > Folder > Shell > cmd
HKLM > Software > Classes > Folder > Shell > cmd > command
```

Now if i only set the command i get this:

[image: There be access keys]

But i would like to indicate that this is opening an interactive dialog, so some ellipsis would be nice, if i edit the `(Default)` value or `MUIVerb` in `cmd` i get this:

[image: There be no access keys]

The C-access-key is gone. I tried something that is common in .NET, like `"_cmd..."` but apparently that won't do here and i do not know what will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place an ampersand (&) before the letter you want underlined.

[image: RegEdit screen shot]

yields

[image: context menu screen shot]

Comment: Excellent example, very 1950's. ;)

Comment: They had RegEdit back then, didn't they?  :)

Comment: I would give you one internets if i could, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I think they kept it in the Bomp, Bah Bomp, Bah Bomp. ;)